# arithmetic sequence of logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

> If $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$ is a geometric sequence with a common ratio $r>0$ and $a_1 > 0$, show that the sequence $\log a_1, \log a_2, \log a_3,... $ is an arithmetic sequence, and find the common difference.

So we know that the first sequence is of the following form: $$a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots = a_1, a_1r, a_1r^2, \dots$$

We also know that the second sequence is of the following form:

$$\log a_1, \log a_2, \log a_3,... = \log a_1, \log a_1 + \log r, \log a_1 + 2 \log r, \dots $$

So the common difference is $\log r$.

I think this is the correct answer as $\log r^n = n \log r$. Is my answer correct?

Comment: That is the right idea.

Comment: @DougM But not the right answer, or..?

Comment: $\log \text{of product}=\text{sum of} \log$. So you are correct.

Comment: Yup, that's the idea. Conversely if $a_1,a_2,.....$ is an arithmetic sequence then $e^{a_1},e^{a_2},....$ is geometric!

Comment: $\{a_n\}$ is a geometric series with initial value $a_1$ and common ratio $r, \{\log a_n\}$ is an arithmetic sequence with initial value $\log a_1$ and common difference $\log r$